# Saving Spark DataFrame created from an oracle query in a hive table?

Tags: dataframe, hive, pyspark

I use impala/hive via HUE on a Cloudera Platform.

If I pull a table from hive into a Spark DataFrame via Pyspark, I can save it as a different table with something like this:

```
sdf.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("schema.PythonTest")
```

Then when I refresh my tables in the HUE under either hive/impala, I can see the new table there and starting writing HQL with it.

However when I pull data from oracle into a Spark Dataframe I get errors when trying that same syntax as above.

```
sdf = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:UN/PW!@blah.bleh.com:port/sid") \
.option("dbtable", mySQL) \
.option("user", "UN") \
.option("password", "pw!") \
.option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
.load()
```

I'm at a loss for explanation.  Why would the syntax work when hive query pulls data into the sdf, but not when oracle does?

The sql for oracle runs fine, and for testing purposes it's only 2 columns and 2 rows.  when I use the type(sdf) function, I can clearly see that i'm successfully creating the Spark DataFrame.

Am I missing some settings or steps?

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you pull the data? To answer this, **Why would the syntax work when hive query pulls data into the sdf, but not when oracle does**, you should provide the error while writing. For HiveContext, `from pyspark.sql import HiveContext hiveContext = HiveContext(sc)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is happening to you:

Make sure you are not stopping and starting the SparkContext.  If so, you are most likely not including the necessary options that are in the default settings, that would allow the Spark DataFrame to save to hive via saveAsTable.

I restarted my kernel, skipped my cell where I was stopping and starting a new SparkContext and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you're getting while pulling the data from Oracle?
Also does the format should be jdbc?

Comment: I am not getting an error when I pull from oracle, it's when I try save the spark dataframe I made from that oracle pull into Hive that I get my error.  Going to find something that may help me recreate this in a public setting.  I think I need to add hive context to the dataframe but I am not sure how to do it.